# Square picasso: загрузить картинку на карту

Tags: picasso, android

Доброго времени суток.
Как используя библиотеку picasso  от square, загрузить картинку на карту для дальнейшего офлайн использования ?

Comment: что бы одна картинка была картой? атлас?

Comment: @Gorets наверно имеется в виду на карту памяти.

Comment: @katso да, хочу чтоб приложение работало в офлайне

Comment: Тебе нужно создать Target и в onBitmapLoaded создать поток, в котором будешь сжимать(по желанию) и сохранять картинку куда тебе захочется. И собственно использовать этот таргет при первой загрузке для сохранения или просто потом проверять если ли у тебя уже эта картинка (Picasso.with(this).load(Url).into(target))

Comment: мне кажется, что для этой задачи использовать picasso вообще ни к чему... Просто скачать файл на СД-карту, и использовать его...

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример таргета используй его для сохранения (если ты имел ввиду сохранение локально)

Picasso.with(this).load(Url).into(target)

```
 private Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                                .getPath()+"/file_name.jpg");
                        try 
                        {
                            file.createNewFile();
                            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, ostream);
                            ostream.close();
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }).start();
            }
            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {
                }
            }
        };
```